# React Native for each item in JSON object returned by AsyncStorage create a component on screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a page currently that stores data into AsyncStorage as a stringified JSON object with the keys: "title", "description" and "rating". For each JSON object stored in Async, I would like to create a new component in a specific  using the component

I have got this being read and converted back into JSON objects in a different page. My issue is I would like to have this data used to populate the screen with premade component called "calendarEntryBox" for each JSON object.

Currently I am able to have one component made for each item in an array, this array has items from Async pushed to it. For testing purposes it is stored with premade entries before Async does anything. However, since this AsyncStorage is async, when I try to put data from Async and store it in this array, the map function within the screens return view has already done it.

How can I take JSON objects retrieved asynchronously, use them to create a component and put this component into a  on a page?

Thanks

---

- Here is the code I have for pushing items to an array from
  AsyncStorage

---

```
const getData = async () => {
        try{

            var allDaysAsString = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Days");
            var allDaysAsJSON = JSON.parse(allDaysAsString);

            Object.keys(allDaysAsJSON).forEach(function(key) {
                // console.log(Object.keys(allDaysAsJSON));
                calendarEntries.push({
                    title: allDaysAsJSON[key].title, 
                    description: allDaysAsJSON[key].description, 
                    rating: allDaysAsJSON[key].rating
                });
            });
```

Here is the code I have for creating a view from each of the items in the array:

```
<View style={styles.calendarContainer}> 
                    {calendarEntries.map((item, key)=>(
                    <CalendarEntryBox key = {key} style = {styles.smallBox} />)
                    )}
</View>
```

This works for test items already stored into the calendarEntries array:

```
 var calendarEntries = [{rating: "bad", description: "hello I am a descrip", title: "what a title this is"},{rating: "bad", description: "hello I am a descrip", title: "what a title this is"}];
```

But when items are added to this array using the getData function, this is not rendered on the users view.

Comment: ummm do you call setState? to rerender

Comment: Sorry, I have used useState to set variables. Are you saying whenever setState is called the whole page is rerendered?

Comment: the component ,in which u uses setState, is rendered again yes

Comment: The problem is right now I have the function which uses AsyncStorage outside of any returned component, is it possible to force that to rerender a component within the pages return?

Comment: how `getData` result set to `calendarEntries`?

Comment: It's not currently, that's what I want to happen. I want the getData function to render calendarEntries

Comment: I dont get it have you ever wrote javascript using modules and promises before? 
if you want to return getData to calendarEntries create a new function in the component call it getEnteries or whatever , like that async getEnteries(){
  this.calendarEntries = await getData();
  //here call setState to rerender 
}

Comment: share a piece of code how u using `calendarEntries` and `getData`. if `calendarEntries` is in render function and u r calling getData there its wrong(u can't use async functions in render). and if `calendarEntries` is outside of render and is an static property maybe you are not updating your page after `getData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes which are provided didn't give enough info how you implemented what you wanted. here is an approach i would take for your case

in your component state i add a property named `calendarEntries`

```
state = {
   calendarEntries: []
}
```

and change getData function to return an array containing the parsed values when resolved(its async)
and in componentDidMount i would call `getData`

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const parsedValuesArray = await this.getData()
    this.setState({ calendarEntries: parsedValuesArray )} // will make page re-render
}
```

and in your render function you use the state property:

```
{
     this.state.calendarEntries.map((item, key)=>(
     <CalendarEntryBox key = {key} style = {styles.smallBox} />)
     )
}
```

the codes shown are simplified as much as i could just to show you an approach. hope it helps